# How to templating json using Reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

Let's say my json like this

```
{
   "Values":[
      {
         "Summary":"What to expect during the Federal Reserve Monetary Council this time? Will the FOMC provide hints about its monetary policy? Watch the Fed FOMC intere",
         "Company":{
            "Id":"852b9932-1ccb-4a23-bb49-3e6772db28bc",
            "Name":"FXStreet"
         },
         "Tags":[
            {
               "Id":"5f91ad8f-26cd-4643-9233-46bd18b03a70",
               "Name":"EURUSD"
            },
            {
               "Id":"f29d883c-d685-47d4-8152-58fbb1fff04b",
               "Name":"Fed"
            },
            {
               "Id":"6e7a9711-3ad6-47bb-8145-84908af2786f",
               "Name":"CentralBanks"
            },
            {
               "Id":"71f084aa-8636-45a8-b08c-ba41a091be85",
               "Name":"USDJPY"
            },
            {
               "Id":"14989b65-d8d2-48b2-85bd-fe3b05d414c0",
               "Name":"DollarIndex"
            }
         ],
         "Id":"3e24b9dc-12fe-4d87-b22e-363b367f6cb8",
         "PublicationDate":"2017-07-26T17:45:00Z",
         "Title":"Live Coverage: FOMC July 26th",
         "Url":"https://www.fxstreet.com/events/live-coverage-fomc-july-26th-201707261745",
         "Author":{
            "Id":"ab05093d-8c7a-4c72-9d94-7765dd7f73be",
            "Name":"Valeria Bednarik"
         },
         "Image":{
            "Url_XtraLarge":"",
            "Url_Large":"",
            "Url_Medium":"",
            "Url_Small":"",
            "Url_XtraSmall":"",
            "Url_Nano":"",
            "Caption":null,
            "Copyright":null,
            "Title":null
         }
      },
      {
         "Summary":"In this webinar, professional trader, money manager and trading coach Jens Klatt and Stefan Friedrichowski, Ph.D. in Physics, quantitative pro-trader ",
         "Company":{
            "Id":"a0fde098-d4e2-4055-b9f2-64693c676b3b",
            "Name":"JFD Brokers Ltd"
         },
         "Tags":[
            {
               "Id":"b97e5e97-9bdb-48aa-af9b-013f3b95c773",
               "Name":"TechnicalAnalysis"
            },
            {
               "Id":"aace4329-8711-4cd6-a796-1cc2ab8484ee",
               "Name":"TrendFollowing"
            },
            {
               "Id":"ab99a439-75d2-49e0-8031-28adeb4ee74f",
               "Name":"Momentum"
            },
            {
               "Id":"7c73a663-0691-427e-965d-3c202a4f903f",
               "Name":"ChartPatterns"
            },
            {
               "Id":"864d4b2c-d423-45f0-9321-9de361d42759",
               "Name":"Candlesticks"
            }
         ],
         "Id":"2e9e7dfa-edf2-45b6-8fa2-a7de8a775e3b",
         "PublicationDate":"2017-07-25T13:00:00Z",
         "Title":"Live Trading Session – Discover tactics of discretionary and quantitative Pro-Traders - Part 4",
         "Url":"https://www.fxstreet.com/events/live-trading-session-discover-tactics-of-discretionary-and-quantitative-pro-traders-part-4-201707251300",
         "Author":{
            "Id":"6d573b01-f601-492f-b25c-b4197554f614",
            "Name":"Jens Klatt"
         },
         "Image":{
            "Url_XtraLarge":"",
            "Url_Large":"",
            "Url_Medium":"",
            "Url_Small":"",
            "Url_XtraSmall":"",
            "Url_Nano":"",
            "Caption":null,
            "Copyright":null,
            "Title":null
         }
      },
      {
         "Summary":"The ECB Monetary Policy meeting is always a key event that provides Euro, US Dollar and other currencies clues. In addition, Mario Draghi is always wi",
         "Company":{
            "Id":"852b9932-1ccb-4a23-bb49-3e6772db28bc",
            "Name":"FXStreet"
         },
         "Tags":[
            {
               "Id":"e6e939d9-7bd8-4337-9cbd-390fc5e89b54",
               "Name":"ECB"
            },
            {
               "Id":"5f91ad8f-26cd-4643-9233-46bd18b03a70",
               "Name":"EURUSD"
            },
            {
               "Id":"a47e3456-d930-4439-8598-65e8b9171e2d",
               "Name":"Eurozone"
            },
            {
               "Id":"6e7a9711-3ad6-47bb-8145-84908af2786f",
               "Name":"CentralBanks"
            },
            {
               "Id":"a6221cea-1f2f-46c6-a623-bc085412ac4c",
               "Name":"EURGBP"
            }
         ],
         "Id":"19b4993f-98ab-4fd3-9274-678482c0bd5c",
         "PublicationDate":"2017-07-20T11:40:00Z",

     "Title":"Live Coverage: ECB rate decision & Mario Draghi speech, July 20th",
     "Url":"https://www.fxstreet.com/events/live-coverage-ecb-rate-decision-mario-draghi-speech-july-20th-201707201130",
     "Author":{
        "Id":"ab05093d-8c7a-4c72-9d94-7765dd7f73be",
        "Name":"Valeria Bednarik"
     },
     "Image":{
        "Url_XtraLarge":"",
        "Url_Large":"",
        "Url_Medium":"",
        "Url_Small":"",
        "Url_XtraSmall":"",
        "Url_Nano":"",
        "Caption":null,
        "Copyright":null,
        "Title":null
     }
  }
]
```

}

What I already try

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class News extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    fetch('/src/components/main/social/data.json')
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        Values: data
      });
    });


  }

  render() {
    if(!this.state.Values) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="flotish">
          <div className="title-flotish">
            <div className="col-md-2">
              <p className="border-after">Time</p>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-10">
              <p>Headline</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="body-flotish">
            <div className="bg-news-flot">
              <div className="col-md-2 bg-terss">
                <p className="timerNews">14:50</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-10">
                <p>{this.state.Values.Summary}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="bg-news-flot">
              <div className="col-md-2 bg-terss">
                <p className="timerNews">14:50</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-10">
                <p>Forex - Dollar mostly flat in early Asia in light regional day</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="bg-news-flot">
              <div className="col-md-2 bg-terss">
                <p className="timerNews">14:50</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-10">
                <p>Forex - Dollar mostly flat in early Asia in light regional day</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default News;
```

I managed to get the state data

[image]

but the problem is when i append on

```
<p>{this.state.Values.Summary}</p>
```

it doesn't shows anything. Maybe i did something not right at my code, Can you guys give a hint or tips how to solve this. Your help really appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Values is an array you cannot do `{this.state.Values.Summary}` you have to access it by index or iterate over the array

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code

```
<p>{this.state.Values.Summary}</p>
```

doesn't show anything, because the component state has an object `Values` only with an array `Values` in it.

```
<p>{this.state.Values.Values[0].Summary}</p>
```

should display `"What to expect during the Federal Reserve ..."`

You might want to put `Values` array directly into the state to omit excessive typing

```
....
then(data => {
      this.setState({
        Values: data.Values
      });
```

Comment: Thanks! for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

`<p>{this.state.Values.Summary}</p>` not working because

> this.state.Values

is an array so you have use .map() to fetch the values inside the array.

inside render method you have to map the array like :

```
this.state.Values.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <div className="col-md-10">
            <p>{item.summary}</p>
        </div>
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

you need something like the following

first you write a stateless comp like above to only DISPLAY every entry in the array of your state data.

Then your stateful component above will look like below

```
render() {
    const summary = this.state.values
    return (
        <div>
        {
          summary.map(entry => (<StateLessDisplayComp key={summary.indexOf(entry)} record={entry} />))

        }
       </div>
    )

}
```

As comment above says. You need to iterate over the state array and then display every entry in it. Map does not mutate your data so it is the best way to do this.

Comment: Thanks! for the hint.